# Git for windows launch gitk context menu with gitk-all

Tags: git, windows-7, gitk

I have Git for Windows installed. When I right click on a project and select `Git History` I get the Gitk window, but every time I do so I need to set the view to see all branches. Even when I edit the view and set it to `Remember`, I still do not get all branches on subsequent visits to Gitk.

Alternatively, I can open the Bash window and type `gitk --all` for the same result.

Both are inconvenient and I'd like to make the default behavior of rght clicking and selecting `Git History` to show `gitk --all`.

How can this be accomplished?

Thanks.

Comment: Related thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60147050/any-way-to-control-the-default-view-of-gitk

Answer (score 0):

Modify registry of that context menu entry to add argument "--all"

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\Open with &gitk --all\command]
@="C:\\Users\\rofro\\scoop\\shims\\gitk.exe --all \"%1\""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\directory\Background\shell\Open with &gitk --all\command]
@="C:\\Users\\rofro\\scoop\\shims\\gitk.exe --all \"%V\""
```