# `gitk` program found using the `where` command but cannot be executed?

Tags: windows, git, path, gitk

I'm trying to run [gitk](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitk) on Windows but the console gives me:

```
'gitk' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

But then, I can do

```
> where gitk
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\gitk
```

How comes?

Comment: Maybe that directory is not in your default search path?  What happens if you run it explicitly as "`C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\gitk`"?

Comment: Good pointer, I just realized while most binaries in the git\bin folder are exe files, gitk is a Linux bash script. I probably need to run it via `git gui`.

Comment: `git gui` and `gitk` are two different programs.

Comment: Yes they are but `git gui` worked from the console and `gitk` can then be executed from the Git GUI dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Stealing the OP's comment:

> Thanks for a (lengthy) explanation, the easiest fix for me was to move from the old msysGit (1.9.5) version to the newer "Git for Windows" builds which has a proper Windows wrapper for gitk.

---

`gitk`, unlike most git commands, is a shell script that invokes Tcl.

If you examine the `gitk` executable file itself, its first few lines are:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Tcl ignores the next line -*- tcl -*- \
exec wish "$0" -- "$@"
```

(At least that's what it looks like on my Linux system; the Windows installer for `gitk` might change that.)

On a Unix-like system, that first line, known as a ["shebang"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)), tells the system to invoke `/bin/sh` to execute the file rather than executing it directly.

The third line executes the `wish` command, which executes the script as a Tcl script.

If you have Tcl installed on your Windows system, you should be able to run `gitk` as a Tcl script using something like this:

```
C:\> tclsh "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\gitk"
```

(Disclaimer: I have not tried this.)

You might also be able to change the command's name from `gitk` to `gitk.tcl` and set up a file association in Windows so it will be invoked correctly. (I'm a little surprised that the Windows git installer didn't do this for you.)

More information on running Tcl scripts on Windows can be found [here](http://www.tcl.tk/faq/tclwin.htm#sec-4-3).

And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10905932/827263) discusses invoking `gitk` on Windows from the context menu rather than from the command line.

Comment: Thanks for a (lengthy) explanation, the easiest fix for me was to move from the old msysGit (1.9.5) version to the newer "Git for Windows" builds which has a proper Windows wrapper for gitk.

Comment: I've stolen your comment and added it to my answer.