# Any way to control the default view of gitk

Tags: gitk, git-for-windows

I use `gitk` from `Git for Windows`. By default it seems to open with a view that only displays the currently checked out branch.

I have a different saved view which is the one that I use 90% of the time.

I normally open gitk from the cmd line (by running `gitk &`), and then have to change the view.

**Is there any way to configure `gitk` to use my preferred view by default?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There does not appear to be a feature for this in `gitk`, however it is pretty easy to manually patch `gitk` to switch to the first permanent view (located for me in `c:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\gitk`):

```
if {[info exists permviews]} {
    foreach v $permviews {
    set n $nextviewnum
    incr nextviewnum
    set viewname($n) [lindex $v 0]
    set viewfiles($n) [lindex $v 1]
    set viewargs($n) [lindex $v 2]
    set viewargscmd($n) [lindex $v 3]
    set viewperm($n) 1
    set viewchanged($n) 0
    addviewmenu $n
    }
    # add these two lines
    set curview [expr {$curview + 1}]
    set selectedview $curview
}
```

This will always select the first permanent view you defined as the default view. If you want to reorder the views, the (hidden) config file is at `%USERPROFILE%\.config\git\gitk`. The setting is called `permviews`.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks, [@mrexodia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1806760/mrexodia).  One improvement I was able to make on your answer was to guard the additional lines so that they won't run if cmd-line args were provided:

```
if {$curview==0} {
    set curview 1 
    set selectedview $curview
}
```

Also, thanks to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9202391/1398635) for helping me understand that I had to run Git Bash as Administrator to be able to modify the `gitk` file.

Comment: `expr` is not needed as $curview is alway 0, therefore result will always be 1 ;)

Comment: Thanks @Maddes, good point -- code updated accordingly.

Comment: Shouldn't `set selectedview $curview` then also be `set selectedview 1` since `$curview` is set to 1?